# How can I extract a particular link from a string of HTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm using the Flickr public API to build a small Express and React app. It returns a 'description' which is a string of HTML:

```
<p>
    <a href="URL">martin_king.photo</a> posted a photo:
</p> 
<p>
    <a href="URL_IMAGE" title="Potato Planting 2018 | FENDT // REEKIE">
        <img src="URL_IMAGE" width="240" height="160" alt="DESC_PHOTO" />
    </a>
</p>
<p> 
    FENDT 412 Vario TMS with the REEKIE ScanStone Separator <br/><br/> Follow Us: <br/> • 
    <a href="URL" rel="nofollow">Facebook - DYNASTYphotography</a> <br/> • 
    <a href="URL" rel="nofollow">Lukaskralphoto Instagram</a><br/> • 
    <a href="URL" rel="nofollow">my personal Instagram</a><br/> • 
    <a href="URL" rel="nofollow">YouTube Channel</a>
</p>
```

The first `a` tag there contains the link I need, I just need some help writing a function/RegExp that can help me extract it. This is my intended result:

```
getFirstLinkFromDescription = string => ... // 1st 'URL'
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to parsing HTML, regex is not that precise.
What you could do is to create `Node`s from that HTML which will make it easier to access the different attributes of those elements, something like:

```js
var html = '<p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/people/129661619@N08/">martin_king.photo</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/129661619@N08/41552236041/" title="Potato Planting 2018 | FENDT // REEKIE"><img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/899/41552236041_7183e7a533_m.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="Potato Planting 2018 | FENDT // REEKIE" /></a></p> <p>FENDT 412 Vario TMS with the REEKIE ScanStone Separator<br /> <br /> You can follow us: <br /> • <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DYNASTYphotography-204551272942391/timeline/" rel="nofollow">Facebook - DYNASTYphotography</a> <br /> • <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lukaskralphoto/" rel="nofollow">Lukaskralphoto Instagram</a><br /> • <a href="https://www.instagram.com/martin939king/" rel="nofollow">my personal Instagram</a><br /> • <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/HighlandBunnyLuv" rel="nofollow">YouTube Channel</a></p>';
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;
var anchor = div.querySelector("a");
console.log(anchor.href);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `getUrl` will return the first `a` tag's `href` or an empty string if the string passed to it doesn't have any `a` tags.

```js
let htmlString = '<div><a href="www.google.com"/></div>';

function getUrl(string){
  let div=document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML=string;
  let firstLink=div.querySelector('a');
  if(firstLink) return firstLink.getAttribute('href');
  return '';
}
console.log(getUrl(htmlString));

console.log(getUrl('<p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/people/129661619@N08/">martin_king.photo</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/129661619@N08/41552236041/" title="Potato Planting 2018 | FENDT // REEKIE"><img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/899/41552236041_7183e7a533_m.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="Potato Planting 2018 | FENDT // REEKIE" /></a></p> <p>FENDT 412 Vario TMS with the REEKIE ScanStone Separator<br /> <br /> You can follow us: <br /> • <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DYNASTYphotography-204551272942391/timeline/" rel="nofollow">Facebook - DYNASTYphotography</a> <br /> • <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lukaskralphoto/" rel="nofollow">Lukaskralphoto Instagram</a><br /> • <a href="https://www.instagram.com/martin939king/" rel="nofollow">my personal Instagram</a><br /> • <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/HighlandBunnyLuv" rel="nofollow">YouTube Channel</a></p>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with regex, but I don't think you need regex for that:

```js
  var someString = '<p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/people/129661619@N08/">martin_king.photo</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/129661619@N08/41552236041/" title="Potato Planting 2018 | FENDT // REEKIE"><img src="https://farm1.staticflickr.com/899/41552236041_7183e7a533_m.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="Potato Planting 2018 | FENDT // REEKIE" /></a></p> <p>FENDT 412 Vario TMS with the REEKIE ScanStone Separator<br /> <br /> You can follow us: <br /> • <a href="https://www.facebook.com/DYNASTYphotography-204551272942391/timeline/" rel="nofollow">Facebook - DYNASTYphotography</a> <br /> • <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lukaskralphoto/" rel="nofollow">Lukaskralphoto Instagram</a><br /> • <a href="https://www.instagram.com/martin939king/" rel="nofollow">my personal Instagram</a><br /> • <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/HighlandBunnyLuv" rel="nofollow">YouTube Channel</a></p>',
        parser = new DOMParser,
        link = parser.parseFromString(someString,"text/html").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;
    
    console.log(link);//"https://www.flickr.com/people/129661619@N08/"
```